# Laravel 5.4 Login Test Cases gives wrong status code.

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am trying to write test cases on Login Page on laravel 5.4
Below is my code.

**tests/unit/LoginTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testURL()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET','/login');
        $this->assertEquals(200,$response->status());
    }

    public function testBlankFields(){
        $response =  $this->get('/login');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $response->assertSee('User Login');
    }

    public function testWrongValues(){
        $response =  $this->post('/login',['email'=>'Brijeshdubey@gmail.com',
                                                  'password'=>'Brijesh']);
        $response->assertStatus(401);
        $response->assertRedirect('/login');


    }
}
```

**See Below Image I am getting Wrong status code 302 instead of 401**

[image]

> **can anyone tell me where i am lackking ??**
>
> > and if anyone knows good way to write test cases in laravel 5.4 then
> >     please let me know i am very confuse.

Thank you

Comment: Can you update the question with the controller method you're calling please?

Comment: I am using inbuilt Auth of laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Response code 302 corresponds to 'found' (http://http.cat/302), which is a commonly used response code in Laravel for when a redirect is given. So, what happens is that you're being redirected.

You could make this return a `JSONResponse` if you wanted, it'd just require some little changes.

Comment: even Same status i am getting

Comment: @BrijeshDubey as stated, its the code issued for a redirect

Comment: can you please help me out what i write in testWrongValues() .This method check email and password if invalid the redirect to same page with status.

Comment: @BrijeshDubey You can still assert for the redirect, its up to you